# Node: How to upload an image with formidable?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, cloudinary, formidable

I want to upload multiple images to cloudinary. In my React client, I have a basic multiple files input. When I click on upload, the data is correctly sent. I use the library `formidable` on my server to parse the files and then upload them to cloudinary.

Here is my client:

```js
<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" placeholder="upload" 
multiple onChange={(e) => uploadImages(files, 3)}/>
```

The api request:

```js
export async function uploadImages(files, userid) {
      try {
            const images = new FormData();
            images.append("fileSubmission", files[0]);
            const res = await ax.post(
              process.env.SERVER_URL + "/upload-images",
              images,
              userid
            );
            return console.log("success", res);
          } 
      catch (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
          }
        }
```

And the server upload route:

```js
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

router.post("/upload-images", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
    form.parse(req, async (_, fields, files) => {
      if (files) {
        const image = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(files, {
          resource_type: "image",
          public_id: `users/${req.userid}/${files.name}`,
          crop: "scale",
          quality: "auto",
        });
        console.log("img uploaded", image.secure_url);
        return res.json({ image: image.secure_url });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.json(err);
  }
});
```

It doesn't work. Would you know how to fix it?

ps: Yes, I know the server code misses a loop to upload all the files one after another. But when i did so, it said `files.forEach is not a function`. Anyways, this code still doesn't work even with a single image.

The error is:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object at validateString

If I console.log `files` once parsed by formidable, the result is:

```js
files {
  fileSubmission: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 1813438,
    path: '/var/folders/hk/l5zpqnyh0000gn/T/upload_38a0a539fa77165b',
    name: 'filename.png',
    type: 'image/png',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2020-06-27T16:30:33.486Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: '/var/folders/hk/l5zpqnyh0000gn/T/upload_38a0a539fa77165b',
      fd: null,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 1813438,
      closed: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work, are you receiving an exception in your code, error message from Cloudinary or something else?

Comment: The error is: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object at validateString" . If I console log "files" once parsed by formidable, I receive an object with a path value.

Comment: I have updated my question with the files output and the error.

Comment: Thanks. Could you try passing `${files.path}/${files.name}` as the 'file' parameter to upload in the Cloudinary `upload( )` method?

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm trying multer now.